# How to send response using Restful webservices?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soapui

I am using Jersey RESTful webservices. i have below web method.

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{name}_{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response deletePerson(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("id") String id) {
    personService.deletePerson("id");
            return Response.status(200).build();
}
```

How can i pass parameters to delete using SOAP UI ?

Thanks!

Comment: "pass parameters to delete using SOAP UI" ... do you want to pass parameter in URL or body? I assume, body. Just wanted to get clarification.

Comment: @Path("/{name}_{id}") means URL right? am not sure..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DELETE is the HTTP method you'll have to use, so you nedd to configure it in [SOAP UI Rest Resource](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/rest-resources-and-methods.html) where you can configure parameters as well